# How To Specify Security Principal (group or user) in X509Certificate2.Export() Instead of Password

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

Using the Certificates.msc tool, I can run the Certificate Export Wizard to export a SSL certificate to a .pfx file. This wizard allows me to either set a password, or to select a security principal (a group or user name).  I choose the 2nd option and select a user name. Works great.

But I now want to do this same export programmatically, and I find that the X509Certificate2.Export() method only allows me to set a password. I see no way to use a security principal to protect the private key.  How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think .NET supports that, but could be wrong. The relevant flag `PKCS12_PROTECT_TO_DOMAIN_SIDS` does not appear anywhere in the source code

Comment: In fact, it's [not even using](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/src/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Windows/Native/Interop.crypt32.cs#L179) the version of the API which [actually supports this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-pfxexportcertstoreex)

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. It’s easy to forget that even after 22 years, .Net is still often just a wrapper around Win32 in many places.  And occasionally it’s an incomplete wrapper.